# Time series prediction when you have limited number of observations

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, time-series

I trained a NN in Keras to predict weekly demand and did all of hyperparameter tuning and the best thing I could get is the following figure. 
My understanding is the predictions are not good because of 2 reasons:

1. I don't have enough observations (weekly demands)
2. The signal itself looks very random and it is hard to predict such signal.

Do you have any experience working with similar time-series data and do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What kind of NN are you using and how do you train the model? The sequence seems quite short.

Comment: I use LSTM (may seem overkill) with the following hyperparameters (after tuning),
n_input = [ 2] (which means shift the times series two time to create more inputs)
n_nodes = [10]
n_epochs = [100]
n_batch = [10]

Comment: Time series prediction is an extremely difficult task in machine learning even if you have tons of history data. One suggestion is to increase the input dimension (number of features in the data), so that we can break down the input/output dependency into some correlations between the output and each feature. Another suggestion is to find adequate length of input sequence, this is more task-based.

Comment: Why is demand in the first week zero?

Comment: @lalala, It actually starts from week_index=1 where demand is 46 (week 0 somehow has sneaked in from data cleaning steps)

Comment: @HanWang, I thought when you have limited observation, you should not increase the number of features (since you don't have enough data to train the model)

Answer (score 1):

Using LSTM is okay. Having more data might not promise good results, but having lesser data will surely give random results.

I suggest the following:

1. increase the data, and keep only quality data in the training. remove or clean any missing data or outlier data. preprocess or smoothen before training
2. visualise the training data, see patterns in each feature, compare correlations with other fields, prioritize fields, ignore fields which are neutrally correlated. and finally do feature selection.
3. perform feature engineering from the existing features, you can do this only when you identify patterns in the data from the previous visualitions.

resources to explore:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/12/12-data-plot-types-for-visualization/
https://dotdata.com/blog/practical-guide-for-feature-engineering-of-time-series-data/